# Scipy UnivariateSpline producing very inaccurate results

Tags: python, scipy

The original functions, plotted with

```
plt.plot(x_list, np.absolute(eig_function)**2);
```

produce analytically expected sinusoidal functions:
[image: 1st regular]
[image: 2nd regular]

```
spl = UnivariateSpline(x_list, np.absolute(eig_function)**2);
plt.plot(x_list, spl(xs))
```

produces

[image: 1st spl]
[image: 2nd spl]

This is not what was expected, from my understanding spline should result in more datapoints of the same value. Why is UnivariateSpline not working?

Comment: please provide the dataset as well so the issue can be reproduced. Also, it appears you call `plt.plot()` once, yet you show two plots

Comment: @Desire what additional code could be required? The vector `eig_functions` is the same for the spline as it is for the regular plotting.

Answer (score 1):

One must use `UnivariateSpline(x, y, s=0)` for accurate results. In other words, the smoothing factor lead to the "smoothing over" of the data in this case.

```
spl = UnivariateSpline(x_list, np.absolute(eig_function)**2, s=0);
plt.plot(x_list, spl(xs))
```